# How to disable a div element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hope everyone is keeping safe and coding a lot.
I am having a problem and have tried every solution but none are working. I do have a HAMBURGER MENU made of DIV's Elements, when open this menu will display all the MENU OPTIONS. So far it is working great but once the SECOND MENU is open I want to prevent the user to use the HAMBURGER MENU until the second menu is closed.
In my last try I have used POINTER-EVENTS: nome but believe it or not, it does stop the second menu from working and not the first one as it was supposed.
I will post here the code in JS and will be so grateful for any tips that will help me:

---

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.nav-wrapper').classList.toggle('change');

    document.querySelector('#home-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("class-nav-1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("#hamburger-menu").style['pointer-events'] = 'none';

  });

  document.querySelector('#close-window').addEventListener('click', () => {

  document.getElementById("class-nav-1").style.display = "none"; 
  document.getElementById('.hamburger-menu').style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  });
});
```

---

Comment: `#hamburger-menu` and `.hamburger-menu` Did you mean to use a class and id selector? `getElementById("#hamburger-menu").` <-- you do not use `#` with `getElementById` I am sure your console has errors

Comment: [A stacksnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) would be great

Comment: You were right. There were an error on my code and I just corrected it but the behavior is always the same. Instead of disabling the hamburger menu the code does always disable the next menu item or just doesn't work at all. Very strange and frustrating as somehow it works, just not the way it is intendend.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is because you are adding other event listener inside the top one. You may need to separate them

```
document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.nav-wrapper').classList.toggle('change');
});

document.querySelector('#close-window').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("class-nav-1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('.hamburger-menu').style.pointerEvents = "auto";
});


document.querySelector('#home-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("class-nav-1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(".hamburger-menu").style.pointerEvents = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for writing. Believe me, I have tried to write the code in so many different ways and always come back the same result. Unfortunately it is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave the practice to control elements' behavior based on information gained from the DOM.

It would be much easier to control the behavior of your menu if you just toggled a boolean value in JS:

```js
const btnFirst = document.getElementById('first')
const ddMenu = document.getElementById('second')
const ddItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dd-item')
const textArea = document.getElementById('third')

// this variable controls the behavior of the main menu
let btnFirstIsEnabled = true

btnFirst.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (btnFirstIsEnabled) {
    btnFirstIsEnabled = false
    ddMenu.classList.remove('hidden')
    btnFirst.classList.add('disabled')
  } else {
    textArea.innerHTML = 'Cannot open dropdown again!'
  }
})

ddItems.forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    textArea.innerHTML = `Clicked: ${e.target.getAttribute('data-val')}`
    ddMenu.classList.add('hidden')
    btnFirstIsEnabled = true
    btnFirst.classList.remove('disabled')
  })
})
```

```css
.main {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main.disabled {
  color: #eaeaea;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.dd-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="third">Clicked:</div>
<div id="first" class="main">OPEN</div>
<div id="second" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <li class="dd-item" data-val="dd 1">Click dropdown item 1</li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-val="dd 2">Click dropdown item 2</li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-val="dd 3">Click dropdown item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just added some coloring to the **main menu** in the snippet to show that it's not active, but the behavior is controlled by setting a `Boolean` variable in JS.

I think it would make your code much simpler if you made it work like this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for writing. It seems a good solution but the problem is: I do not have a normal menu or even clickable normal buttons. I do have only a picture and a hamburger menu that I did build using 3 div elements. Once this hamburger menu is clicked a new div opens up and show a real menu. I just need the hamburger menu to be disabled while the user is working on any item of the menu otherwise it will be quite a mess. I need to find a way to disable the burger menu temporarily.

Comment: @Edson without your exact code & markup only indicative solutions (like my answer) can be given. The main point is: there are two states of your menu: 1. the hamburger is active & the dropdown is not, 2. the hamburger is inactive & the dropdown is active. These two states are coupled (mutually exclusive), so they can be controlled with one `Boolean` variable. This is what I understood from your question. If you toggle that variable with `onclick` events, and set up the `if-else` conditions, then it should solve your problem.